# jacoco - analyzed 0 classes

Tags: jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am trying to use jacoco for code coverage of my java project (maven build). This is the build section of my pom. I see that my test class getting executing with all the tests (2 of them) passing. However, Jacoco says "Analyzed bundle with 0 classes". Any pointers would help.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration combine.self="override" />
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>integration-tests</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>${skip.integration.tests}</skip>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*IT*.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <argLine>${testArgLine} -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=1048m</argLine>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!-- JACOCO - code coverage -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.5.201505241946</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent-integration</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <destFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
                        <propertyName>testArgLine</propertyName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

                <execution>
                    <id>post-integration-test</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/jacoco-it.exec</dataFile>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-it</outputDirectory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```